# Plant identification and care

Tags: identification

Here is an album

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b0Bc.jpg

It does not seem to be doing so well, so I would like to identify it and take steps to take care of it.

Comment: Can you post your pictures directly so we can see without clicking on the link?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a member of the mint family; a distinguishing feature is that the leaf margins are scalloped, where many mints are sharp toothed. One commonly grown pot plant with scalloped edges is lemon balm, but this plant seems a deeper green than usual for lemon balm. If you could pinch off a bit of a leaf and see if the cut end has any kind of odour that would help narrow it down.

The leaves have been eaten by some kind of leaf cutter. In fact you can see the culprit at the bottom left of the image, a green caterpillar, possibly winter moth (Operophtera brumato). It might help to examine the plant carefully and squeeze any caterpillars hard.

Comment: In which picture did you see a caterpillar? I feel like I am blind!